# AngularJS - Continuosly watch over a collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I'm trying to build a real watcher for a collection in my app and, at first, I thought that **Angular** would provide me everything I needed.

I mean, I had the `$watch`, both shallow and deep. and the `$watchCollection`, a `$digest` cycle that loops over my `$scope-exposed` variables through the `dirty checking` mechanic and triggers all the watchers...

Great! What else could I need?

**Wrong!**

Turns out that `$watchCollection` gets triggered only at the first change of the watched variable...
And that's it for the mighty watchers... why???

After a [reality check](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5R3_ToFRGg), I realized that I needed some kind of horrible loop to check this collection, or else I had to implement some sort of callback to do this, whenever the var gets modified.

Anybody knows how this can be done in the cleanest way possible?

---

**Important note:**
I don't why, but it seems that some horrific bug in my code was gnawing my ankles...

Now that I've fixed it, both `$watchCollection(expr, foo)` and `$watch(expr, foo, true)` works as expected...

I was mislead by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821083/service-with-promise-and-watchcollection-not-updating-the-values) SO post , in which an user comments:

> [...] I don't see anything in your code that makes the subsequent requests (to check for new messages). Where does that happen?

I took his comments as proof of my hypothesis... my bad!

I'm leaving this question as a *memento*

Comment: passing true as third param to watch should work.... scope.$watch('data', function (newVal) { /*...*/ }, true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a regular `$watch` will do this if you utilize the 3rd parameter (`objectEquality`).  This will check if the objects are equal and not just references.

So, you can use something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('prop', function(value) {
   // do something
   }, true);
```

The `true` value tells Angular to compare objects instead of references.

The [documentation for this feature](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) is with `scope`.

Comment: It works, indeed. That's what a `deep watch` is supposed to do. 
Please take a look at my update

Answer (score 1):

below solution is bit of an hacking solution and should only be used if $watchCollection does not work. rather than watching on the array, watch on json

```
$scope.$watch(function() { 
  return angular.toJson($scope.array); 
},
function() {
  // watch logic
}
```

I am using above solution to watch on multiple arrays like below:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { 
  return JSON.stringify([$scope.array1, $scope.array2]); 
},
function() {
  // watch logic
}
```

you can user either of JSON.stringify or angular.toJson.

Comment: Hacky, but could have its uses.
Please take a look at my update